# Fail to make HTTPS requests in pod internal network

Tags: kubernetes

Fail to make HTTPS requests in pod network (192.168.0.0/16)

I have created a new set k8s cluster, `10.100.1.1` (master), `10.100.1.2`...`10.100.1.5`, pod internal network is `192.168.0.0/16`

e.g. metrics-server is assigned to node3 (`10.100.1.3`), with pod ip address `192.168.12.123`.

when I ssh to node3 and do a curl (`curl -k https://192.168.12.123`), it can return result

but if I ssh to nodes other than node3, and do a curl (`curl -k https://192.168.12.123`), 
it will return `curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received`

Basically all cross-nodes pod HTTPS requests (`192.168.x.x`) fails

Comment: What CNI are you using and can you put output of `kubectl get pods -o wide` command?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with firewall between nodes in your cluster.
Make sure that you open required [ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) between master and worker nodes in your Kubernetes cluster.

I hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

finally figured out the problem.

from calico config, the MTU is 1500
from ifconfig, the MTU of the interface is 1450

the solution is to `kubectl edit configmap calico-config`, change MTU value from 1500 to 1430, and restart.

this solves the issues